# ¿Qué tipo de dato remplaza Tinyint en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando tratando de ejecutar mi consulta en MSSQL pero me genera un error

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  authKey VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  accessToken VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  activate TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  role INTEGER NOT NULL,
);
```

Mens. 2716, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1
Columna, parámetro o variable nº 7: no se puede especificar un ancho de columna en el tipo de datos tinyint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tener en cuenta:

```
| Tipo de datos  |                                             Intervalo                         |    Almacenamiento  |
|----------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------|
|  bigint        |  De -2^63 (-9.223.372.036.854.775.808) a 2^63-1 (9.223.372.036.854.775.807)   | 8 bytes            |
| int            |  De -2^31 (-2.147.483.648) a 2^31-1 (2.147.483.647)                           | 4 bytes            |
| smallint       |  De -2^15 (-32.768) a 2^15-1 (32.767)                                         | 2 bytes            |
| tinyint        |  De 0 a 255                                                                   | 1 byte             |
```

Revisar el comentario en el código:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  authKey VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  accessToken VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  activate TINYINT NOT NULL, --aqui esta la solucion
  role INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Mayor información:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql